# How to Recover in C++ from memcpy "Bus Error" from FPGA?

Tags: c++, error-handling, mmap, memcpy

Everything I have read suggests that `memcpy` does not throw an exception so try-catch statements cannot be used to handle such an error.  I have been provided memory addresses and ranges by the hardware team and am accessing them through `mmap`, but there have been some integration issues (i.e. things for them to fix).

One DDR channel works perfectly while the same code doing the same operations often dies for another channel.  The program simply halts with "Bus Error" printed on the terminal.

Once this is figured out, memory interactions should be much smoother, but this interface accepts memory operations from another device (i.e. another team).  I can try to validate any incoming operations, but then there is the possibility that the hardware team does something weird as well to change what is valid or simply results in "Bus Error" for a valid operation.

So how can I keep my C++ application from dying due to future/unexpected changes from another team?  Do I need to set up a signal handler?  Are there other options?

Comment: Are you perhaps accessing the memory by unaligned pointers? Some architectures like armv8 do not allow unaligned access to device memory. Bus error is not something you catch, you fix the cause instead.

Comment: Are you sure your hardware is ok? If you are, do your pointers have valid values? And are you using volatile pointers? It is hard for me (and probably others) to say anything useful without more information

Comment: Bus error is a signal so a signal handler is the only thing capable of catching it. But then how do you plan to recover? I guess you could try to remap the memory page in the hopes that it fixes the issue but your only solution is to either recover so that memcpy can continue with the exact same instruction or terminate the offending thread; better the entire process. Personally I would fork a new child process for every operation that can fail so that the subprocess can die

Comment: If it's C++, try avoiding `memcpy`. The only remaining use case for that function in user code is type-punning; in C++20 that usage is safely handled via `std::bit_cast`. The wise choice would then be to ban its usage and reject it in code reviews.

Comment: Bus Error is a  common error message to see when you write to non-writable memory.

Comment: @Red.Wave - what is the C++14 alternative to `memcpy`?

Comment: The alternative in all versions of C++ is the assignment operator `=`.

Comment: As wrote earlier, the only use case for memcpy, up untill C++20 was type punning. Otherwise you could use `std::copy` in `<algorithm>`. For type punning you can copy the interface of of C++20 `std::bit_cast`, replace C++20 constraints with `static_assert` and carefully call `std::memcpy`.

Comment: @Red.Wave - appreciate the suggestion and I have made the change away from `memcpy`.  Unfortunately, even with a try-catch statement around it, still the same behavior with a SIGBUS signal.

Comment: `memcpy` is a low level function; it doesn't have any sort of error handling logic, by design it is supposed to run ar ultra high speed. As a consequence, memcpy usage errors most often remain uncaught, unless they hit the HW protection constraints and trigger HW faults. You are obviously passing out of memory values in; that's why I advice you off `memcpy` in the 1st place.

Comment: Avoiding `memcpy` is a red herring. Sure, you can argue that as a code-cleanliness measure, `std::copy` is better. But that doesn't change anything about the error behavior. Guess what `std::copy` calls internally when you copy trivial types? [`memcpy`'s sister function `memmove`](https://godbolt.org/z/oEMcnxne5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding @user2725742's suggestion of using long jumps, here is a version that converts the signal into an exception. I use it to catch both bus and segmentation fault errors because frankly I don't know a good way of generating bus errors.

We start by defining an [RAII](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii) class to set and restore signal handlers since we will mix exceptions and global state changes. This is a rather minimal, non-moveable version but sufficient for our needs.

```cpp
#include <signal.h>

#include <cerrno>
#include <system_error>

class SignalRegistration
{
    int sig;
    struct sigaction oldaction;
public:
    using action_fun = void (*)(int, siginfo_t*, void*);

    SignalRegistration(int sig, action_fun fun)
    : sig(sig)
    {
        struct sigaction action {};
        action.sa_sigaction = fun;
        action.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
        if(sigaction(sig, &action, &oldaction))
            throw std::system_error(
                  errno, std::generic_category(), "sigaction");
    }
    SignalRegistration(const SignalRegistration&) = delete;
    SignalRegistration& operator=(const SignalRegistration&) = delete;
    ~SignalRegistration()
    { sigaction(sig, &oldaction, nullptr); }
};
```

We can now define the actual handler for the signals. The idea is this:

1. We activate signal handlers for SIGBUS and SIGSEGV
2. We set the state for a [`longjmp`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/siglongjmp.3p.html)
3. If the signal handler is invoked, it saves the signal state and returns via `longjmp`
4. The `longjmp` returns to the place where it was set. There the signal state is converted into an exception

In order to make this work in a multithreaded environment, the longjmp buffer and saved signal state need to be a thread local variable.

```cpp
#include <sstream>
// using std::ostringstream

class FaultHandler
{
public:
    struct SigState
    {
        sigjmp_buf env;
        siginfo_t info;
    };
    static inline thread_local SigState instance = {};
private:
    static void sighandler(int /*sig*/, siginfo_t* siginfo, void* /*ucontext*/)
    {
        instance.info = *siginfo;
        siglongjmp(instance.env, 1);
    }
    SignalRegistration bus, segv;

public:
    FaultHandler()
    : bus(SIGBUS, &FaultHandler::sighandler),
      segv(SIGSEGV, &FaultHandler::sighandler)
    {}
    [[noreturn]] static void raise()
    {
        std::ostringstream ss;
        ss << "Received signal " << instance.info.si_signo
           << " code " << instance.info.si_code
           << " address " << instance.info.si_addr;
        int errcode = instance.info.si_signo == SIGBUS ? EIO : EFAULT;
        throw std::system_error(errcode, std::generic_category(), ss.str());
    }
};
```

Now we can use this to guard the `memcpy` or *some* other functions. Specific requirements:

1. They must not involve the creation of new objects with non-trivial destructors. To be precise: If the signal handler is invoked, automatic variables which were created between `sigsetjmp` and `siglongjmp` will be forgotten without invoking their destructor first
2. The function should be [async-signal-safe](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html). See the section *Undefined behavior* in [`man 3 siglongjmp`](https://man.archlinux.org/man/siglongjmp.3.en#Undefined_Behavior) (curiously absent from other man-pages with the same title)

Anyway, `memcpy` is safe to use with this:

```cpp
#include <cstring>
// using std::memcpy

void* memcpy_fault(void* out, const void* in, std::size_t nbytes)
{
    FaultHandler check;
    if(sigsetjmp(FaultHandler::instance.env, 1))
        FaultHandler::raise();
    return std::memcpy(out, in, nbytes);
}
```

And here is a quick test to see it working:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    char buf[10];
    try {
        memcpy_fault(buf, nullptr, 4);
    } catch(std::system_error& err) {
        std::cout << "Caught exception: " << err.what() << '\n';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A signal handler in combination with these seem in order...

```
static sigjmp_buf jmpbuf;
siglongjmp(jmpbuf,signum); // call from within signal handler

if(sigsetjmp(jmpbuf,1)) {
    std::cout << "Something bad happened\n";
} else {
    // Normal operation, basically saving a checkpoint before a dangerous operation
}
```